# How can I connect with a MySQL database with Hibernate in a GWT app?

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I tried these tutorial but my application wasn't working: 
http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html

I use GWT SDK 2.6.1
I downloaded from Hibernate the 4.2.3 version

I think I wrote in the hibernate.cfg.xml file everything. This is the first 2 tag from the cfg.xml file:

```
 <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:3306</property>
```

I get this error in eclipse (I don't understand why get I ClassNotFoundException caused by jdbcDriver):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:123)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:84)
... 55 more
```

Edit:
I also have mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar to the project

Comment: do you have `HSQL` DB Connector driver?

Comment: Yes, I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar added to the project

Comment: Sorry I want to say you must use MySQL dialect to connect to MySQL DB Like this :`<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>`

Comment: thanks, I corrected it! But doesn't work

Comment: Please post your updated hibernate config file.

Answer (score 0):

To connect MySQL Your hibernate config file should have these properties:

`<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB</property>`

Updated

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/feladatlapok</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password"/>
<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<mapping resource="com/google/musicstore/domain/Record.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="com/google/musicstore/domain/Account.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="com/google/musicstore/domain/Elem.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I corrected the cfg.xml file but I get this error again:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
....

Comment: @user3292988, Can you post your corrected xml file?

Comment: Your `connection.url` must use `jdbc:mysql`.

Comment: @user3292988, answer is updated with your correct cfg file. Please check.